# Is there a way to hide title bar on a specific page on sharepoint

Tags: page-viewer-web-part, title-column

I want to hide the title bar on Just one page of the sharepoint. I am using pageviewer webpart, and want to show only portion of the sharepoint page without the title bar, navigation bar, logo etc. So just to see if there is a way to hide title bar on the page so when I use page viewer the title bar doesn't show up

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the Title bar and Navigations only, then just add "?isdlg=1" to the Page url in the web part properties. So your url will look like this:

```
~your-site~/SitePages/Test.aspx?isdlg=1
```

Comment: How can I put ?isdlg=1 at the end? When I click edit properties of that site page, it takes me to edit name of the site which already has .aspx at the end (which is not editable)

Comment: Not on the Page. I have mentioned it - "WEB PART properties" (the page viewer web part inside which you want to show your page). You might be adding a link to the page you want to show right? There after the URL put "isdlg=1"

Comment: It didn't work. I got 404 error. I am using a url from sharepoint wikipage.

Comment: Can you show how your url looks?

Comment: You can follow this - https://davidlozzi.com/2014/10/28/sharepoint-hiding-ribbon-and-more-with-isdlg/

Comment: My url is like this :  MT/IT/Subjects/SitePages/Learns Videos.aspx?isdlg=1              Now I got the error saying something is wrong!!

Comment: First try the complete url without isdlg. If that gives you the complete page without error ( along with navigations and title), then try putting ?isdlg=1